# How to get location updates in certain time interval only?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-location

In my android application I want to get location updates only for certain time interval say like from morning 9 to evening 9.

How is that doable. Please share your thoughts on it.

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem.
use it in a running background service or something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hofday = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);    //getting the current hour of day

    if (hofday<21  && hofday>9){    //between 9am. and 9pm.

        //start collecting gps data


    }
    else{

        //it is not between 9am. and 9pm.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Thank you! do you mind to mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You set an alarm for 9 am and 9 pm.  Then in your broadcast receiver for the first you turn on location updates, and for the second you turn it off.

Comment: you mean after setting alarm. You want me to make to service ON and OFF to get location updates.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial on how to [schedule repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). For location updates I recommend using [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html).